# Фигуры на turtle

Tags: python, turtle

TURTLE

Надо сделать вот такие фигуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Их параметры:

Размеры крышек коробок:

- Треугольную крышку следует сделать со стороной 70.
- Квадратную крышку следует сделать со стороной 60.
- Пятиугольную крышку следует сделать со стороной 50.
- Шестиугольную крышку следует сделать со стороной 40.
- Семиугольную крышку следует сделать со стороной 45.

Код который есть:

```
from turtle import *

pensize(3)
# Функция для вырезания равносторонней фигуры. Помогает вырезать крышки коробок
def box_top(size, sides):
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    color("black")
    for k in range(sides):
        forward(size)
        left(360/sides)
    color("green")
    end_fill()
    penup()

penup()

# Требуется вырезать пять фигур. 
# Ниже допишите программу так, чтобы получить схему из пяти вариантов как в задании. 
goto(-100,-50)
box_top(50, 9)

# это важная функция, её не удаляй!
exitonclick()
```

Comment: изменил добавил

Comment: а в чем проблема то? вы не понимаете что в функции называется `sides`?

Comment: нет, мне надо нарисовать эти фигуры которые указаны в картинке но я не понимаю какие надо делать goto() и какие форварды.

Answer (score 2):

ужас, куда мы катимся :(

итак, в задаче надо нарисовать равносторонние треугольник, прямоугольник (он же квадрат), пятиугольник, шестиугольник и 7-угольник

в приведенном коде, если не полениться и запустить его, рисуется 9-угольник

т.е. функция `box_top(size, sides)` при вызове

```
box_top(50, 9)
```

рисует 9-угольник

подозрительно

интересно, а если вызвать

```
box_top(100, 3)
```

она нарисует треугольник со стороной 100?

учитывая что фигура рисоваться начинается с левого нижнего угла (который задается внешним `goto`), то

```
goto(-100,-50)
box_top(50, 3)

goto(-50,-50)
box_top(100, 4)
```

возможно нарисует впритирку треугольник и квадрат?

Теперь если понятно что поставить начальную координату можно через внешний `goto(x0, y0)`, то как расположить фигурки относительно друг друга?

что нужно знать

1. длину стороны
2. угол между сторонами - 360 / кол_во сторон
3. синусы/косинусы

ну и дальше математика 7 класса

например для 6-угольникв

```
y0_шестиугольник = y0_квадрат
x0_шестиугольник = x0_квадрат + сторона квадрата + сторона шестиугольника * cos(360 / 6)
```

Comment: А можно полный ответ чтобы вставить в код? я в 2 классе не понимаю что такое синукс и косинус

Comment: во втором классе задача точно не решается - подбирайте на глаз тогда, впрочем высоту рядов вы выставить сможете и 4 из 5 фигур спозиционировать :)))))) а тригонометрические функции вообще-то проходят в начале 1 четверти 2 класса, так что не знаю, что ваш учитель делал, все силы на преподавание русского бросил? :)

Comment: `тригонометрические функции вообще-то проходят в начале 1 четверти 2 класса` это же была шутка, да?

Comment: @Danis, да нет, судя по тому как Арим сформулировал вопрос, какой словарный запас использует и как строит фразы, плюс какая ему дана задача еще как проходят :)